# How can i list all packages in a Github Package Registry repository from the command line?

Tags: github, github-package-registry

Let's say that we have the Github package registry repository https://maven.pkg.github.com/someOrganization . How can I cat the list of all packages in this repo into a txt file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [Preview API for GitHub Packages](https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#github-packages). You can query it in GraphQL using:

```
query($login: String!) {
  organization(login:$login) {
    registryPackages(first:10, packageType:MAVEN) {
      nodes {
       name             
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will output something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "organization": {
      "registryPackages": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "package1"
          },
          {
            "name": "package2"
          }            
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the time of writing this requires both:

- Valid Token with `org:read` and `packages:read`
- `Accept` header for preview API: `application/vnd.github.packages-preview+json`

Now because you want to do this over the command line, you could `curl`ing it. There's already a good answer on how to use `curl` to access GitHub's GraphQL API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42021388/1174076

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you