# Ansible github_packages

Tags: github, ansible, github-package-registry, ansible-galaxy

There are two releases that can be obtained from a GitHub repo (Binary Releases and Package Releases) as shown below:

[image: GitHub SS]

I want to use Ansible to retrieve Package Releases from my GitHub Repo

I did some searching on Ansible docs and found a collection `community.general.github_release` but this gives the latest `Release` binaries of the repo and not `Package Releases`.

Can anyone help if they know a collection that can fetch Package Releases from GitHub ?

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Github GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) (as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894135/how-can-i-list-all-packages-in-a-github-package-registry-repository-from-the-com) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021113/how-to-use-curl-to-access-the-github-graphql-api/42021388#42021388)) such as:

```yaml
  #
  # Tasks that may be included in an Ansible playbook or role depending on your needs
  #

  # Some variables to define to identify your repository
  # They may be set as playbook or role variables as well
  # You'll need a Bearer token (see https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)
  - set_fact:
      bearer_token: YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN
      repository_name: repository-name
      repository_owner: repository-owner

  - name: Retrieve packages for repository
    uri:
      url: https://api.github.com/graphql
      method: POST
      body: '{"query":
          "query { repository(name: \"{{ repository_name }}\", owner: \"{{ repository_owner }}\") {
            packages(first:10) { nodes { name, packageType, latestVersion {
              version, files(first:100) { nodes { url } }
            } } }
          }
        }"'
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
        Accept: "application/vnd.github.packages-preview+json"
        Authorization: "bearer {{ bearer_token }}"
    register: github_packages_json
```

This will provide an output like:

```json
  {
    "json": {
        "data": {
            "repository": {
                "packages": {
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "latestVersion": {
                                "files": {
                                    "nodes": [
                                        {
                                            "url": "https://pkg.githubusercontent.com/xxx/some-url"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "url": "https://pkg.githubusercontent.com/xxx/another-url"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "version": "my-package-1.2.3"
                            },
                            "name": "my-package",
                            "packageType": "DOCKER"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Depending on `packageType` you may need to perform different action. For example, a `DOCKER` `packageType` would require you to pull the image such as:

```yaml
  - name: pull docker
    shell: docker pull docker.pkg.github.com/{{ repository_owner | lower }}/{{ repository_name }}/{{ docker_image_name }}:{{ docker_image_version }}
    vars:
      docker_image_name: "{{ github_packages_json.json.data.repository.packages.nodes[0].name }}"
      docker_image_version: "{{ github_packages_json.json.data.repository.packages.nodes[0].latestVersion.version }}"
```

Comment: @Pierre B. Thank you, i will test this and let you know. That's an ANsible playbook that you provided right ?

Comment: Just tested it and works like a charm! Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Thanks @VonC and Mervin, you're welcome! Happy to help. It's a set of task that may be included in a playbook or a role, I'll edit to emphasize that

Answer (score 2):

The [community.general.github_release](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/github_release_module.html) Ansible role is part of the [`ansible-collections/community.general`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general) code.

Its source code [`source_control/github/github_release.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/3f1c93cccf72a3ab28f2f97e259f199c7e715c96/plugins/modules/source_control/github/github_release.py#L60-L63) shows that is is using [github3.py](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), the library for using GitHub's REST API.
Specifically, the [`latest_release`](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository.latest_release) endpoint ([code here](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/blob/404ea04710247407ca9c6bc4f2b89f0e464c4a5e/src/github3/repos/repo.py#L2146-L2156)) uses the [`GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/latest`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release) REST API.

However, a "Package Release" is, for `github3.py` (used by the Ansible role), **[an asset](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.ShortRepository.asset)**, with an ID you can find in a [`github3.repos.release.Release`](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.release.Release): the [`original_assets`](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.release.Release.original_assets) will give you all the [assets id](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.release.Asset).

You would therefore need to write a role similar to `latest_release`, using the version returned by `latest_release` in order to call `github3.repos.release.Release`, get the assets ID and download the one you need using [`asset(asset_id)`](https://github3py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.release.Release.asset)

Comment: I have no experience in writing a custom role but I'll see in it. Thank you so much

Comment: I really don't think this is correct.  The "assets" are only available off of a "release".  These are the files that you would see in each "release".  If there are no releases (as in the example that the question uses), then the API will simply return an empty array, and there's no way to proceed further.  Perhaps I'm wrong, but as far as I can tell, API access to *packages* (which are a relatively new feature) is only available in the Github v4 GraphQL API (also a *relatively* new feature).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Possible indeed: I was confused by the term asset in https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-releases. There is no mention of "package(s)" in https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases.